# Install in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I had the latest version of KendoUI installed in Visual Studio 2012 on my laptop. 
This Weekend I installed Visual Studio 2013.

When I started VS2013 KendoUI wasn't installed in VS2013.
I exited VS2013 and tried to reinstall KendoUI. but I got the message that it was aleready installed.

I would like an utiliy that adds the existing installation into the new Visual Studio.

Is there Another way to fix this other than wating for the next release of KendoUI?

Answer (score 1):

There is still no integration with VS2013. You have to proceed as described in http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5

Answer (score 0):

I just installed VS 2013 and ran into the same problem.  I tried repairing it from the Telerik control panel but that didn't help. There is a remove option.  I didn't try that but I would think if you remove it and reinstall it, this would work.